# How do I call the SecondViewController on Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, button, controllers

I'm new to programming on Xcode and can't really find out how to call the `SecondViewController` window by pressing a button. The button is called Ingredients; I tried entering "`-(IBAction)Ingredients:(id)sender;` in the `ViewController.h` and but then saw that there was the `FirstViewController.h` and `SecondViewController.h`, same with First and second `ViewControllers`.

Anyways, what I wanted to do was be able to click the "Ingredients" button and make it go to a completely different window, with a different background, and other texts as the first one. I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself correctly :(. Let me try an Image:

[image]

Comment: You can't go to the different window, you can only change your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, get some basic knowledge about `Objective C`. Go to Apple developer website and you will get tons of tutorials & sample codes to learn.

Now, for your question:-

In `firstViewController.m`

```
First import SecondViewController.h
```

On button click:-

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are not using story board so simply call:

```
FLSecondViewController *object = [[FLSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FLSecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:object animated:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry where do I put this?

Comment: On the event you change your `viewController`

Answer (score 1):

Why go for another window? a View controller may be enough,set up a navigation controller and push the second viewcontroller.

[a sample tutorial on navigation controller](http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)Ingredients:(id)sender 
{
  SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

edited: Typical an iOS app has only one window which acts as a container for views, so you work most of time only with views. Change one view with another depend on desired content to be presented.